# Pass parameter of selected line to another Ruby view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner in ruby. I have a table in a view, that when I click on the line / item it should pick up the ID of the selected line and move to the other view that will be triggered, I am 3 days searching on and I can not implement.

The view that should take the ID or another parameter so that in the other I can treat the select to bring more detailed information >>:

```
<td>
 <%= link_to pedido.id, detalhes_backoffice_pedidos_path(:pedido_id => 
  pedido.id) , :onclick=>"window.open(this.href,'create_company', 
  'height=600, 
  width=600');return false;" %>            
</td>
```

The view ("popup") that is called when clicked on the request id. Obs.:Tried in countless ways, and at the moment she is like this ... >>>>

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
 <div style='display: block;' class="col-xs-6 esquerdo ">
 <label>Num.pedido<%= pedido.id %></label> <br>
 <label>nome</label> <br>
 <label>telefone</label> <br>
</div>
```

Controller>>

```
class Backoffice::PedidosController < BackofficeController
.....
def detalhes
 render :layout => "application"

@pedido = params[:pedido_id]

end
```

I am totally lost, after trying so much .... If you can pass some example link for study, it will be very useful too !!

Comment: It's Ruby, not RUBY. No need to yell, and it's not an acronym.

Comment: Where are you seeing RUBY?

Comment: It was in your title. I edited it to calm things down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has become clear that you just need to use AJAX to show the selected pedido details on the page. Rails has an easy way to do this.

First put in a table with a div below it for displaying the pedido info. Each row in the table has a link to the controller action that will do the AJAX. Use `remote: true` to make the link AJAX, so the user is not taken to another page.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<% @pedidos.each do |pedido| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to 'More info on this Pedido!' fetch_info_pedidos_path(pedido), remote: true %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>

<div id="pedido-info"></div>
```

Make the route for the action in the pedido controller. This is in `routes.rb`

```
resources :pedidos do
  get :fetch_info, on: :member
end
```

This should create a path that looks like `/pedidos/:id/fetch_info` with the name `fetch_info_pedidos`

The link in the table will make a js format request along this route so the controller action must be ready to handle that. The pedido id will come as a parameter called `:id`

```
def fetch_info
  @pedido = Pedido.find params[:id]
  respond_to :js
end
```

Since it responds to a js format request it will respond with js content, not html - that means we need to have a js file as the view, but before we make that let's make a partial for displaying pedido info. This can be dropped into any view using the `render` method. It will be in `app/views/pedidos/_pedido.html.erb` (you have to use an underscore at the start of the file name to show it is a partial) You can put any content in here you like, using the `pedido` variable to refer to the pedido. Here's an example:

```
<h2>Pedido!</2>
<p>number: <%= pedido.id %></p>
<p>nom: <%= pedido.nom %></p>
<p>telefone: <%= pedido.fone%></p>
```

Finally let's make the js that gets passed back to the browser. This will be an erb file like other views. It will just put the _pedido partial as the content to the div under the table. `app/views/pedidos/fetch_data.js.erb`

```
$('#pedido-info').html("<%= j render @pedido %>");
```

That's all you need. The `j` here escapes the output of the `render` method so that it plays nicely inside a javascript string.

There's a bit of Rails magic happening here, which I will explain, because, as you would learn at any wizard training school: "don't use any magic you don't completely understand"

The `render` method expects the name of a partial to render, and optionally some local variables to pass. If it's given only an ActiveRecord object, it will look for the partial that matches the class name of the object (`Pedido` goes to `_pedido.html.erb`) and it passes the object as a local variable also with matching name. so `render @pedido` gets translated to `render partial: 'pedido', locals: {pedido: @pedido}`

I haven't tried any of the code in this answer, I just wrote it off the top of my head, so you may have to jiggle it a bit to get it to work.

here's [a link to a page](https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy) you might have come across if you had simply Googled how to do this. It says essentially the same as what I have said here, except his AJAX brings in a whole collection of objects, not just one at a time.

Comment: I love you man! I have not tested it, but with these explanations it will be easy to make it work, thanks for the help. And about the partials I already knew, and believe me if you want, I already found this site that you passed the link, but did not fully understand and for that reason did not work. But many thanks !! 
I understand how js works in rails.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood the question, but it seems to me you just need to link to the `detalhes` action for each `pedido` in the table.

here is the table:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<% @pedidos.each do |pedido| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to 'Detalhes this Pedido!' detalhes_path(pedido) %></td>
    <td>More table data related to this pedido</td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and in the routes you would have something like this:

```
resources :pedidos do
  get :detalhes, on: :member, as: 'detalhes'
end
```

Comment: The idea is this. But in the view that you say to iterate the "pedido", this is it. Now I need to get this selected item in another view so that I can show more details about it.

Comment: The view ("popup") that is called when clicked on the pedido. Obs.:Tried in countless ways, and at the moment she is like this ... >>>>

     <div class='container-fluid'>
     <div style='display: block;' class="col-xs-6 esquerdo ">
     <label>Num.pedido<%= pedido.id %></label> <br>
     <label>nome</label> <br>
     <label>telefone</label> <br>
     </div>

Comment: You want the extra pedido info to appear in a _popup_ window?!! Don't you realise this is highly annoying to most users, and would be blocked by default in most browsers?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a div under the table and let the pedido info appear there?

Comment: I really had not thought of that, as it's just an MVP. I just could not understand how this DIV on the table would work, could you give me an example? TKS!!

Comment: OK, I made a whole new answer with detailed instructions on how to do it. See my other answer.